# System.CodeDom.Compiler as nuget-package

Tags: c#, compilation, nuget, package

The whole day I've been seaching for the `System.CodeDom.Compiler` - namespace in nuget-packages. I only found the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` (Roslyn ?) but it seems as the namespace I'm searching for is not included. Does anyone know if there's a package containing that namespace?

Edit:
This is the code I got for now. But Visual Studio 2015 cannot find the `CodeDom` in namespace `System`

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ICA.CubeSeven.Dynamic
{

    public class Class1
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of the Framework are you targeting?

Comment: ahh this was the problem... in the project.json-file there is for default no target-framework. After adding one it works! Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo I found the problem myself...
In the project.json we need to add a targetframework. For me it was adding the framework-section in project.json (for default the template doesnot add a framework):

```
{
      "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not in a package, it's in `System.dll` and is part of the framework.

Just make sure you have `using System.CodeDom.Compiler;` in your file.

Comment: I thought it, too. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and wanted to create a nuget-package. But Visual Studio here says on the using "The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. (are you missing an assembly reference?) Any ideas??