# System.CodeDom.Compiler for dnxcore50

Tags: c#, codedom, .net-core

I'm trying to port some C# code to target CoreClr.
Part of this code creates "in memory" assemblies using System.CodeDom.

This question seems similar to [System.CodeDom.Compiler as nuget-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426737/system-codedom-compiler-as-nuget-package), except that question only addresses framework target of dnx451. I am trying to target dnxcore50.

Have I've missed something? Not found the right package? Or does dnxcore50 use a different compiler in a different namespace? Also tried Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers but that report that it is incompatible with dnxcore50.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core uses Roslyn. CodeDom is the old way of doing things.

Your code might not be portable in the same structure that it is now.

Here are a few tutorials to get you started:

- http://blog.comealive.io/Syntax-Factory-Vs-Parse-Text/
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143896/understanding-the-basics-of-roslyn/

Comment: Sorry - maybe I didn't explain enough - my understanding was that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is "Roslyn" and I have had no issue in converting my code to use this on an installed .Net framework. The issue is I cannot find a dnxcore50 package that is compatible.

Comment: 1.1.0 seems to be what they are working on. Maybe try this repository: https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev/